# Google Maps: place ID array over 10 doesn't work

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

I created a Google map with several markers. For the management I created an array according to the place ID, to display details of the different points of interest. The problem is that from the tenth array details are no longer displayed. I use the free Google API. Has it by chance a certain limit in the management of getService? Did I do something wrong? Below is the image and the code!

[image: Google Maps Paris - Marker and details with array]

```
var paris = [
  ['Le Palais de l&apos;Élysée', 48.8704156, 2.3167538999999806, {placeId: 'ChIJR-OmjM5v5kcRIi9Yekb0OC4'}],
  ['Rue du Faubourg Saint-Honoré', 48.8729217, 2.3104977000000417, {placeId: 'ChIJ9UXDFMZv5kcRJM1tqvbRfjY'}],
  ['Champs Élysées', 48.8657844, 2.307314099999985, {placeId: 'ChIJMXZjGMVv5kcRmVlGwtKSa3w'}],
  ['Arc de triomphe', 48.8737793, 2.2950155999999424, {placeId: 'ChIJazhtdOxv5kcRqV9clsepEIc'}],
  ['Musée du Louvre', 48.8606111, 2.3376439999999548, {placeId: 'ChIJD3uTd9hx5kcR1IQvGfr8dbk'}],
  ['Grand Palais', 48.86610909999999, 2.3124543999999787, {placeId: 'ChIJ0dzuSNBv5kcRa6BHUVdFm0k'}],
  ['Place de la Concorde', 48.8656331, 2.3212356999999884, {placeId: 'ChIJAQquYc1v5kcRLKslDuENAxg'}],
  ['L&apos;eglise de la Madeleine', 48.8700435, 2.324550199999976, {placeId: 'ChIJ7xwB9TJu5kcRtsJIlPxT918'}],
  ['Grande Roue de Paris', 48.8651962, 2.3220541000000594, {placeId: 'ChIJCfZJWc1v5kcRg_05SQL-RNg'}],
  ['8e arrondissement', 48.87187219999999, 2.3176432000000204, {placeId: 'ChIJdWkEFsZv5kcRwBqUaMOCCwU'}],
  ['Gare Saint-Lazare', 48.8763827, 2.325446800000009, {placeId: 'ChIJgwCdnTVu5kcRADA9YHBZa1s'}],
  ['Jardin des Tuileries', 48.8634916, 2.327494300000012, {placeId: 'ChIJAQAAMCxu5kcRx--_4QnbGcI'}],
  ['Hotel Splendide Royal Paris', 48.87096269999999, 2.315414099999998]
];

function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 15,
    center: {lat: paris[0][1], lng: paris[0][2]}
  });

  setMarkers(map);
  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);


  for(var i=0; i < 12; i++){
    service.getDetails(paris[i][3], function(place, status) {
      if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          map: map,
          position: place.geometry.location
        });
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
          infowindow.setContent( "<strong>" + place.name + "</strong>" +
            "<br />" + place.formatted_address +
            "<br />" + "<a target='_blank' href='"+ place.website + "'>" + place.website +"</a>" +
            "<br />" + "Tel: " + place.international_phone_number
          );
          infowindow.open(map, this);
        });
      }
    });
  }
}

function setMarkers(map) {
  for (var i = 0; i < paris.length; i++) {
    var strut = paris[i];
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: {lat: strut[1], lng: strut[2]},
      map: map,
      title: strut[0]
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Does it show any message in console?

Comment: It silently fails if status != "OK"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quota for the Javascript API services is optimized for responding to human interactions.
It is not recommended to use the client-side services for batch querying.

When the API loads, up to 10 requests can be made upfront, but after that there is a rate limit that will be enough when there is a human typing address, but not when there is code trying to geocode more and more addresses.

In order to get more than 10 results at once, you'd need to use the Geocoding API web service before loading the map, to geocode all the results in batch. This is particularly appropriate if your map will be displaying these results to many users.

Alternatively, you could paginate results (10 per page) and either force a delay between pages, or reload the API for each page. Both approaches have their downsides: a delay is annoying for users, reloading the API is slower and consumes your Maps JavaScript API quotas faster. That is, if you do expect users to often go beyond the first page.

Maybe you could just load the first 10 with a nice animation, and then wait for 10 seconds and from this moment throttle at 0.8 QPS(Queries Per Second) or so and include some animations to not let the user get bored :)

Answer (score 1):

Most likely it occurs since you are getting `OVER_QUERY_LIMIT` status code for the remaining two requests.

According to [Status Codes](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search#PlaceSearchResponses)

> OVER_QUERY_LIMIT indicates that you are over your quota.

According to [Usage limits](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/usage#usage_limits)

> The Google Places search services share the same usage limits.
>   However, the Text Search service is subject to a 10-times multiplier.
>   That is, each Text Search request that you make will count as 10
>   requests against your quota

In order to bypass this limitation you could consider the following solution: once OVER_QUERY_LIMIT status is received, wait for a certain delay and then perform request again, in that case all the places could be requested.

**Example**

```js
var paris = [
  ['Le Palais de l&apos;Élysée', 48.8704156, 2.3167538999999806, { placeId: 'ChIJR-OmjM5v5kcRIi9Yekb0OC4' }],
  ['Rue du Faubourg Saint-Honoré', 48.8729217, 2.3104977000000417, { placeId: 'ChIJ9UXDFMZv5kcRJM1tqvbRfjY' }],
  ['Champs Élysées', 48.8657844, 2.307314099999985, { placeId: 'ChIJMXZjGMVv5kcRmVlGwtKSa3w' }],
  ['Arc de triomphe', 48.8737793, 2.2950155999999424, { placeId: 'ChIJazhtdOxv5kcRqV9clsepEIc' }],
  ['Musée du Louvre', 48.8606111, 2.3376439999999548, { placeId: 'ChIJD3uTd9hx5kcR1IQvGfr8dbk' }],
  ['Grand Palais', 48.86610909999999, 2.3124543999999787, { placeId: 'ChIJ0dzuSNBv5kcRa6BHUVdFm0k' }],
  ['Place de la Concorde', 48.8656331, 2.3212356999999884, { placeId: 'ChIJAQquYc1v5kcRLKslDuENAxg' }],
  ['L&apos;eglise de la Madeleine', 48.8700435, 2.324550199999976, { placeId: 'ChIJ7xwB9TJu5kcRtsJIlPxT918' }],
  ['Grande Roue de Paris', 48.8651962, 2.3220541000000594, { placeId: 'ChIJCfZJWc1v5kcRg_05SQL-RNg' }],
  ['8e arrondissement', 48.87187219999999, 2.3176432000000204, { placeId: 'ChIJdWkEFsZv5kcRwBqUaMOCCwU' }],
  ['Gare Saint-Lazare', 48.8763827, 2.325446800000009, { placeId: 'ChIJgwCdnTVu5kcRADA9YHBZa1s' }],
  ['Jardin des Tuileries', 48.8634916, 2.327494300000012, { placeId: 'ChIJAQAAMCxu5kcRx--_4QnbGcI' }],
  //['Hotel Splendide Royal Paris', 48.87096269999999, 2.315414099999998]
];


function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 15,
    center: {lat: paris[0][1], lng: paris[0][2]}
  });

  //setMarkers(map);
  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
  displayPlaces(map,service,infowindow,paris);
}


function displayPlaces(map,service,infowindow,data,currentIndex){
  
  currentIndex = currentIndex || 0;
  if(currentIndex >= data.length)
      return;

  service.getDetails(data[currentIndex][3], function(place, status) {
      
      if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OVER_QUERY_LIMIT) {
          console.log(status + currentIndex);
          setTimeout(function() {
              displayPlaces(map,service,infowindow,data,currentIndex);
          }, 200);
      }      
      else if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          map: map,
          position: place.geometry.location
        });
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
          infowindow.setContent( "<strong>" + place.name + "</strong>" +
            "<br />" + place.formatted_address +
            "<br />" + "<a target='_blank' href='"+ place.website + "'>" + place.website +"</a>" +
            "<br />" + "Tel: " + place.international_phone_number
          );
          infowindow.open(map, this);
        });

        currentIndex++;
        displayPlaces(map,service,infowindow,data,currentIndex);

      }
    });
}



google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initMap);
```

```css
 #map,
        html,
        body {
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
            height: 100%;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```